# Creating json-object with auto increment for POST reqest to save in DB

Tags: java, json, web-services, spring-boot

I used springboot to create webservice and connect with my angular project 
so, I used save() in CrudRepository to insert and update  but when I send POST request with JSON in POSTMAN to insert new object I get an error:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
"path": "/update"
```

updating the existing id in database is fine but for new id it fail.

JSON example

> {
>      "id": 5,                  <------auto_increment
>      "name": "John",
>      "description": "handsome"
>   }

```
@RestController{
@Autowired
    Connect connect;
@PostMapping("/update")
    public Topic updateTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic){
        connect.save(topic);
         return topic;
    }
}
```

> >

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "info")
public class Topic implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String description;

    public  Topic (){

    }


    public Topic(String name,String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Topic(Long id,String name,String description){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

How do I write json to match Autoincrement and insert new id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem , I just changed

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

to

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: my senior told me it's about mariaDB and hibernate something.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to generate ID for new entities in your JSON at all.

see the javadoc of  [`Serializable save(Object object)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)):

"Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.)"

And so, in simple words, you should generate your new entity JSON without ID and let Hibernate generate new IDs for new entities. That way the new ID will follow the ID generation strategy you've chosen for this entity (in your case `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`).

Comment: Thank you zuckermanori , I try to generated with this one {
 "name":"Dodo",
 "description":"cat"
} then it showed {
    "timestamp": "2018-06-27T06:28:22.939+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
    "path": "/add"
}     T__T

Comment: Then it looks like you have a different problem. Have you tried saving the above mentioned entity without ID from the backend itself? jist to see where the problem is, because as explained above, Hibernate should be fine with the empty ID.